# Traffic not being routed through Cisco VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, networkmanager, cisco, kali-linux

I'm unable to use my school's VPN correctly in Linux.
This is what I did:

1. Installed a fresh x64 Kali linux (latest).
2. Updated all current packages through apt-get
3. Installed the required vpn packages through apt-get.
4. Configured the VPN as "Cisco Compatible VPN (vpnc)"
5. Entered everything according to the Cisco config file which I downloaded

This is the .pcf file I downloaded from my school's site: [port configuration file](http://goo.gl/Cbs8e2)

This is the screenshot of the configuration window in kali: [image: VPN Config screenshot]

When I select the vpn from the Networkmanager GUI I get a successful login message and the tray icon shows a little lock, indicating the connection is secure I guess.
I also get a tun adapter in my ifconfig: [ifconfig output](http://goo.gl/mEbH7X)

But that's it, my public IP remains the same and I can't access my school's servers.

I tried:

- Restart of network manager
- System reboot

Answer (score 0):

I no longer have to use a VPN client to connect, but when I did I used these guides to help debug issues that I would often have with it when connecting.

- [Configuring an IPSec Tunnel Between a Cisco VPN Client for Linux and a VPN 3000 Concentrator](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/vpndevc/ps2284/products_configuration_example09186a0080094673.shtml)
- [VPNClient - Ubuntu official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VPNClient)

If neither of these pan out for you I'd start searching Google for "cisco vpn client debug linux". There were other resources that might help you out as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking after solutions to Cisco IOS actual problems, you may consider querying my search engine at http://vouters.dyndns.org/ with the keyword "Cisco". You'll find there some 5 documents closely related to Cisco IOS. This includes full details about a Shrew VPN Client and a Cisco IOS router configuration. I assembled it to set up an operational VPN between France (running Shrew) and Mexico city (where the Cisco IOS router was). I simply lost too much time because of my firewall settings. Otherwise, you would perhaps have also benefit from a Radius AAA using FreeRadius and Cisco IOS. Perhaps a future opportunity with someone else willing the solution at low cost.

In the hope this helps.
Philippe Vouters (Fontainebleau/France)